# 3 Slashes in .htaccess URL rewrite

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

Basically I have created a PHP Website which uses API of other website to pull data .
My problem is that I am getting Error 404 .

I added codes below to `.htaccess`

```
 RewriteRule ^sort/(.*) index.php?by=$1
```

this made website.com/sort/gender work !

But then I have another page name user.php
I have added

```
RewriteRule ^profile/(.*) user.php?name=$1
```

To make `website.com/profile/username`

But I want To Show

```
website.com/profile/username/bookmarks
```

Instead Of

```
website.com/profile/username?by=bookmarks
```

My Full .htaccess code below :

```
RewriteEngine on
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteBase /
ErrorDocument 404 /404.php
RewriteRule ^sort/(.*) index.php?by=$1
RewriteRule ^profile/(.*) user.php?name=$1
RewriteRule    ^privacy/?$    privacy.php    [NC,L]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have some missing flags and incorrect regex in your existing rewrite rules.

Your complete .htaccess would be like this:

```
ErrorDocument 404 /404.php

RewriteEngine on
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^sort/([^/]+)/?$ index.php?by=$1 [L,NC,QSA]

RewriteRule ^(profile)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ $1/$2?by=$3 [L,NC,QSA]

RewriteRule ^profile/([^/]+)/?$ user.php?name=$1 [L,NC,QSA]

RewriteRule ^privacy/?$ privacy.php [NC,L,QSA]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just add another rewriterule with 2 wildcards in it like this:

```
RewriteRule ^profile/(.*)/(.*) user.php?name=$1&by=$2
RewriteRule ^profile/(.*) user.php?name=$1
```